# can't integrate my awesome template into my reset password e-mail view

Tags: templates, bootstrap-4, reset-password

I'm working on resetting email password, but i cant get the same design it seems that i can't load **Bootstrap**' and **Fontawesome5** , i m using an **CDN**

**This is for web integrators , templating views**

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<!-- --------------------------------------Font awesome ------------------------------------------------------------->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--  -------------------------------------Bootstap V4------------------------------------------------------------ -->

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Réinitialisation du mot de passe</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

this is what i get in an ordinary php page [[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0dBT.png)

this is what i get into my e-mail with the same code [[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgXfR.png)

this is the image also [[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ5Rt.png)

Comment: You can't include external stylesheets (and scripts!) into e-mail template. You need to place your styles inline.

Comment: Do you meen that i need to download all stylesheets and include it into my project ? i did the same thing when i link an image but i get the same result

Comment: Your e-mail template should be simplified as possible. When you display only a button, you don't need whole bootstrap framework, only class for that button.